# File processing in c?

Tags: c, file, image-processing, io

I have been given a raw file that holds several jpg images.  I have to go through the file, find each jpg image, and put those images each in a separate file. So far I have code that can find each where each image begins and ends. I also have written code that names several file names I can use to put the pictures in. It is an array: char filename[] , that holds the names: image00.jpg - image29.jpg .

What I cannot figure out is how to open a file every time I find an image, an then close that file and open a new one for the next image. Do I need to use fwrite()? Also, each image is in blocks of 512 bytes, so I only have to check for a new image every 512 bytes once I find the first one. Do I need to add that into fwrite?

So, to summarize my questions, I don't understand how to use fwrite(), if that is what I should be using to write to these files.
Also, I do not know how to open the files using the names I have already created.

Thanks in advance for the help. Let me know if I need to post any other code.

Comment: `char filename[] = {"image00.jpg"};` is a wrong declaration, it should be `char filename[] = "image00.jpg";` you have assigned char*[] to char[].

Comment: Editing out the code sample feels unfriendly and unhelpful. I appreciate that other have pointed out some errors in it, but the current state of your question leaves me very unclear on what you *do* and *do not* know and what you *can* and *can not* do right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [`fopen(rawfilename, "rb");`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) to open the raw file for reading. and [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) to read from it.
2. Use `fopen(outfilename, "wb");` to open output file for writing and [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/) to write to it.
3. As mentioned in my comment, you are assigning `char *[]` to `char*`, use `char filename[] = "image00.jpg";` instead.
4. Don't forget to close each file after you finish its processing (r/w) (look at `fclose()` at the same site of other links)
5. Decide how much bytes to read each time by parsing the [jpeg header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format). Use [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) to allocate the amount of bytes needed to be read, and remember, for each allocation of buffer you need to [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/free/) the allocated buffer later.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any [book on C programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/File_IO) should cover the functions you need. As MByD pointed out, you'll want to use the functions fopen(), fwrite(), and fclose().

I imagine your code may include fragments that look something like

```
/* Warning: untested and probably out-of-order code */
...
char **filename = {
    "image00.jpg", "image01.jpg", "image02.jpg",
    ...
    "image29.jpg" };
...
int index = 0;
const int blocksize = 512; /* bytes */
...
index++;
...
FILE * output_file = fopen( filename[index], "wb");
fwrite( output_data, 1, blocksize, output_file );
fclose(output_file);
...
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more sensible to generate the file name from the index, probably using `sprintf()` to format the name?

Comment: David, I changed my filename to what you have, but I get a warning:
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Comment: @Joey - You should declare it as array: `char *filename[]`.